# True or false: Every harmonic function on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ has a harmonic conjugate.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

True or false:

Every harmonic function on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ has a harmonic conjugate.

I saw a question on this site:"Show
Ω
is simply connected if every harmonic function has a conjugate"

But I know that

1)"$\Bbb C \setminus\{0\}$ is not simply connected"

2. "If $f = u + i v$ is analytic then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic conjugate of each other"
3. "The function $u$ is harmonic if $\Delta^2u = 0$ where $\Delta$ is a Laplacian operator"

Please help me.

Comment: What is the harmonic conjugate of the absolute-value function?

Comment: A famous example: $\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)$. This is the real part of the complex logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

Is false. As the user [Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee) said, consider $\frac{1}{2}\log|z|=\log(x^{2}+y^{2})$ in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. This function does not have a harmonic conjugate: see the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948563/logz-has-no-harmonic-conjugate-in-bbb-c-setminus-0-different-proof?rq=1).